# How to read in a file to a 2d char array

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a txt file to a 2d char array. My issue is the way I am trying to do it generates an error. How would you fill this array with a txt file?

```
 public char[][] readFile(String filename) {

    try {

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(new File(filename));



        int x= scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        char [][] maze= new char [x][y];
        for(int i=0;i<maze.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< maze[i].length; j++){
                maze[i][j]= scan.next().toCharArray();

            }
        }


        return maze;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: it appears to be a compiling error caused on the line maze[i][j]= scan.next.toCharArray();

Comment: You are trying to store a char array in a char

Comment: It now says Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: That means you are trying to read the input from the file even after reaching `End Of File`.

Comment: Provide the contents of the file you are trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
maze[i]= scan.next().toCharArray();
```

just do this. But it may give you exception at runtime when `toCharArray()` returns an array that is exceeded the size of your column(y) size declaration.

Comment: That is building the array except the test code is saying "readFile not building array correctly." So I am not sure what is going on now

Comment: Make sure your character in .txt file is separated by a single space.

Comment: like this :  1 1 1 1

Comment: It is not the text file because I submitted it to the test server and it is giving me that error

Comment: Your Output/Master Output:

readFile not building array correctly                                                                                                      
readFile building array correctly